# How to send an SLD style to GeoServer using AJAX?

Tags: geoserver, javascript, style, sld, geoserver-rest-api

The question title sums it up pretty much, this is the code that I actually have:

```
// Build a XML string from the XML object
var xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml)

// Send it with Ajax
$.ajax({
    url: "geoserver/rest/styles",
    method: 'POST',
    data: xml_string,
    process_data: false,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/vnd.ogc.se+xml"
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("admin:geoserver"));
    },
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function () {
        console.log("New SLD style uploaded.")
    },
    error: function (x, i, e) {
        console.log(x.status + " " + x.responseText);
    }
});
```

The AJAX call succeeds but It results in the creation of two files in the GeoServer `datadir`, the XML for the style metadata and the associated SLD file:

This is the content of the SLD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld">
org.geotools.styling.StyledLayerDescriptorImpl@37c2ff8b
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

What is wrong with the Ajax call that makes the SLD looks like this ?

**EDIT:**

Here's the header of the SLD file I'm trying to post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
<NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>layer_name1</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>layer_name1</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Name>name</se:Name>
        <se:Rule>
    [...]
```

GeoServer does not return any error:

`2016-11-02 11:34:50,533 INFO [catalog.rest] - POST Style layer_name1`

**Edit #2 (Logs):**

*Log #1 (GeoServer developper log)*

```
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/styles, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/styles, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/styles, QueryString: null'; against '/'
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/styles, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/styles, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/styles, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/styles, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/styles, QueryString: null'; against '/rest/**'
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /rest/styles, QueryString: null with /rest/**
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache found an entry for basic, admin:bfa584f5598433a3c1fe16b00acc9c43
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/rest/styles'; to: '/rest/styles'  and httpMethod= POST
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [GET]
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/rest/styles'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=false
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [POST, DELETE, PUT]
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/rest/styles'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=true
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - returning ADMIN
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/rest/styles]
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/rest/styles]
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/rest/styles]
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 22 locking in mode WRITE
2016-11-02 11:45:24,552 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 22 got the lock in mode WRITE
2016-11-02 11:45:24,614 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisting style layer_name1
2016-11-02 11:45:24,614 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4 to styles/layer_name1.xml
2016-11-02 11:45:24,630 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16 to global.xml
2016-11-02 11:45:24,630 INFO [org.geoserver.catalog.rest] - POST Style layer_name1
2016-11-02 11:45:24,630 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 22 releasing the lock in mode WRITE
2016-11-02 11:45:24,630 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/, QueryString: wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage'; against '/web/**'
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/, QueryString: wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage with /web/**
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 22 locking in mode WRITE
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 22 got the lock in mode WRITE
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/screen.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/print.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/geoserver.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/ie.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-11-02 11:45:30,028 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/js/jquery.inline-info.js to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
```

*Log #2 (GeoTools developper log):*

```
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/, QueryString: wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.admin.GlobalSettingsPage'; against '/web/**'
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/, QueryString: wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.admin.GlobalSettingsPage with /web/**
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 21 locking in mode WRITE
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 21 got the lock in mode WRITE
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/screen.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/print.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/geoserver.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/ie.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-11-02 11:48:04,078 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-11-02 11:48:04,094 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/js/jquery.inline-info.js to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-11-02 11:48:04,125 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 21 releasing the lock in mode WRITE
2016-11-02 11:48:04,125 DEBUG [org.geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/html; charset=utf-8
2016-11-02 11:48:04,125 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-11-02 11:48:12,066 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/, QueryString: wicket:interface=:52:form::IFormSubmitListener::'; against '/web/**'
2016-11-02 11:48:12,066 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/, QueryString: wicket:interface=:52:form::IFormSubmitListener:: with /web/**
2016-11-02 11:48:12,066 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:48:12,066 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:48:12,066 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:48:12,066 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-11-02 11:48:12,066 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 20 locking in mode WRITE
2016-11-02 11:48:12,081 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 20 got the lock in mode WRITE
2016-11-02 11:48:12,081 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16 to global.xml
2016-11-02 11:48:12,097 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16 to global.xml
2016-11-02 11:48:12,097 DEBUG [org.geoserver.logging] - CONFIGURING GEOSERVER LOGGING -------------------------
2016-11-02 11:48:12,128 DEBUG [org.geoserver.logging] - GeoServer logging profile 'GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING.properties' enabled.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,012 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:26,121 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:44,249 DEBUG [org.geotools.xml] - schemaLocation found: http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd
2016-11-02 11:48:44,249 DEBUG [org.geotools.xml] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/sld: http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd ==> jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.8.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-sld-14.2.jar!/org/geotools/sld/v1_1/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd
2016-11-02 11:48:44,264 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,264 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,280 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,280 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,280 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,280 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,280 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,280 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,280 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,280 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,295 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,311 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,311 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,311 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2016-11-02 11:48:44,311 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2016-11-02 11:48:44,311 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - StyleImpl added 1 feature types
2016-11-02 11:48:44,311 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - StyleLayerDescriptorImpl added 1 styled layers
2016-11-02 11:48:44,311 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-11-02 11:48:44,311 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-11-02 11:48:44,327 INFO [org.geoserver.catalog.rest] - POST Style layer_name1
```

Comment: please add a short example of the actual XML/SLD you post and any relevant errors from the GeoServer log file

Comment: I edited the main post.

Comment: try turning logging up to developer and trying again

Comment: Edited the post with 2 log outputs (geoserver and geotools developper logging)